# The 'SQLNCLI' provider is not registered on the local machine, sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlncli

Working on deploying an application from my development box to a client.  On the client when I run my exe, I get the error "The 'SQLNCLI10' Provider is not registered on the local machine.

I'm developing in SQL Server 2012.  I have tried installing sqlncli.msi on the target machine with no luck.

Can anyone tell me what package I need to install on the client machine to get my app to work?  And if possible provide a URL to said package?

Thanks!

Comment: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured out I needed the 2008 version as opposed to the 2012 version.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=123718&clcid=0x409

Comment: Same for me. I have Office 2013 installed, I googled the error (`Power Pivot -> Manage -> Existing Data Sources -> Edit -> Test` to actually see the error) and came here.

Comment: The link you provided is returning a 404 error. Is there another link to go to instead?

Answer (score 5):

Are you perhaps working on a 64 bit machine and used the 32-bit install?

Here's the 64-bit link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188401&clcid=0x409

Answer (score 3):

Use SQLNCLI11 for connecting to SQLserver 2012

eg:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=trv6s177;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=DPVCube_Stage
```

Downloads

```
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239649&clcid=0x409
```

X86 Package (sqlncli.msi)

```
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239650&clcid=0x409
```

X64 Package (sqlncli.msi)

Comment: Correct answer. SQLNCLI10 is SQL 2008, 11 is SQL 2012

Answer (score 1):

Some updates:

SQLNCLI11 works on windows 10 as well, and it can connect SQL 2012 and 2014 (not tested on later SQL versions)
This is the latest version available

At the time of writing, the most updated package can be found here: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50402
SQL Server® 2012 Native Client - QFE

From Microsoft:

It is not recommended to use this driver for new development. 
The new OLE DB provider is called the Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (MSOLEDBSQL) 
which will be updated with the most recent server features going forward.

Article: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017

Download link: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Install the sqlncli10 provider on your machine.

The sqlncli10 provider for SQL 2008 R2 can be downloaded from here.

[X86 package.](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188400&clcid=0x409)
[X64 package](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188401&clcid=0x409)