# The 'SQLNCLI10.1' provider is not registered on the local machine for VS 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlncli

I have already visited all [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264845/the-sqlncli-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-sql-server-2012) answers but they are not working for me,
I have installed Native server but still getting the same error

[image]

but still facing this error:

[image]

I also download OLE DB drivers from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I believe SQLNCLI10.1 drivers are from SQL Server 2008 R2. VS2019 itself wouldn't require that, though. Are you trying to open an ancient project that does?

Comment: "...still facing this error...". Please specify where exactly you are facing it. Otherwise, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: The error is in question, `The SQLNLI10.1 provider is not registered on the local machine`